# How do I place NaN when computing the average rating for each movie in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am working with the MovieLens dataset, basically there are 2 files, a .csv file which contains movies and another .csv file which contains ratings given by n users to specific movies.

I did the following in order to get the average rating for each movie in the DF.

```
ratings_data.groupby('movieId').rating.mean()
```

however with that code I am getting 9724 movies whereas in the main DataFrame I have 9742 movies.
I think that there are movies that are not rated at all, however since I want to add the ratings to the main movies dataset how would I put NaN on the fields that have no ratings?!

Comment: Some problem with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by unique `movieId` form another column, for same order is add [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
movies_data = pd.read_csv('ml-latest-small/movies.csv')
ratings_data = pd.read_csv('ml-latest-small/ratings.csv')

mov = movies_data['movieId'].sort_values().drop_duplicates()  
df = ratings_data.groupby('movieId').rating.mean().reindex(mov).reset_index()
print (df)
      movieId    rating
0           1  3.920930
1           2  3.431818
2           3  3.259615
3           4  2.357143
4           5  3.071429
      ...       ...
9737   193581  4.000000
9738   193583  3.500000
9739   193585  3.500000
9740   193587  3.500000
9741   193609  4.000000

[9742 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

```
df1 = df[df['rating'].isna()]
print (df1)
      movieId  rating
816      1076     NaN
2211     2939     NaN
2499     3338     NaN
2587     3456     NaN
3118     4194     NaN
4037     5721     NaN
4506     6668     NaN
4598     6849     NaN
4704     7020     NaN
5020     7792     NaN
5293     8765     NaN
5421    25855     NaN
5452    26085     NaN
5749    30892     NaN
5824    32160     NaN
5837    32371     NaN
5957    34482     NaN
7565    85565     NaN
```

EDIT:

If need new column to `movie_data` DataFrame, use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
movies_data = pd.read_csv('ml-latest-small/movies.csv')
ratings_data = pd.read_csv('ml-latest-small/ratings.csv')

df = ratings_data.groupby('movieId', as_index=False).rating.mean()
print (df)
      movieId    rating
0           1  3.920930
1           2  3.431818
2           3  3.259615
3           4  2.357143
4           5  3.071429
      ...       ...
9719   193581  4.000000
9720   193583  3.500000
9721   193585  3.500000
9722   193587  3.500000
9723   193609  4.000000
```

---

```
[9724 rows x 2 columns]

df = movies_data.merge(df, on='movieId', how='left')
print (df)
      movieId                                      title  \
0           1                           Toy Story (1995)   
1           2                             Jumanji (1995)   
2           3                    Grumpier Old Men (1995)   
3           4                   Waiting to Exhale (1995)   
4           5         Father of the Bride Part II (1995)   
      ...                                        ...   
9737   193581  Black Butler: Book of the Atlantic (2017)   
9738   193583               No Game No Life: Zero (2017)   
9739   193585                               Flint (2017)   
9740   193587        Bungo Stray Dogs: Dead Apple (2018)   
9741   193609        Andrew Dice Clay: Dice Rules (1991)   

                                           genres    rating  
0     Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy  3.920930  
1                      Adventure|Children|Fantasy  3.431818  
2                                  Comedy|Romance  3.259615  
3                            Comedy|Drama|Romance  2.357143  
4                                          Comedy  3.071429  
                                          ...       ...  
9737              Action|Animation|Comedy|Fantasy  4.000000  
9738                     Animation|Comedy|Fantasy  3.500000  
9739                                        Drama  3.500000  
9740                             Action|Animation  3.500000  
9741                                       Comedy  4.000000  

[9742 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: I tried your code, however it seems to place a value of NaN over a movie which is rated and rated highly actually by a number of users. I've uploaded an image of what I mean to Imgur, you can check it out here: https://imgur.com/HHscfpQ

Comment: @SaadSawash - Problem is output was assign to new column, use `df = ratings_data.groupby('movieId').rating.mean().reindex(mov).reset_index()`

Comment: but I am actually trying to add the values as a column into my current DF! That's my goal.

Comment: @SaadSawash - Yes, then add `.reset_index()` - answer was edited

Comment: That worked on most of the movies, however I tried doing .tail() to see the last movies in the dataset and found out most of them had a rating of NaN, I checked the ratings.csv file to check whether they were rated or not, and they were. For example the movie Flint (2017) has a rating. https://imgur.com/0Wf2oAU

Comment: @SaadSawash - Can you test now? Maybe some values missing in `df['movieId']` from `ratings_data['movieId']`

Comment: Same issue, still getting a NaN.

Comment: @SaadSawash - what is source of data? Is possible test it?

Comment: the data is from https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ specifically the one for education and development which is a 1MB zip file. I haven't done any modifications to it, I am working on its raw form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210364/discussion-between-jezrael-and-saad-sawash).

Comment: @SaadSawash - I think typo with `mov = movies_data['movieId'].sort_values().drop_duplicates()`, for me working correct, edited answer.

Comment: still having issues